# Can a link to download media file be streamed on for the video

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, download

Hey there i have some url's from external site that returns some media file as download.

The response is media file as an attachment.

I am trying to stream from this link in my site i am doing to learn things.

And i was having problem with just playing it providing the link to normal html js players.

I guess the headers are reason for this.

The file response is with headers

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment
Content-Length:259639762
Content-Range:bytes 0-259639761/259639762
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Fri, 05 Apr 2013 18:05:43 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 05 Mar 2012 17:23:58 GMT
Server:nginx
```

that triggers the download.

Can anyone tell me if its possible to stream this media inside a page using the js players,or is it impossible at all.

This is for learning purposes and it would be even helpfull if someone could give me more insight into how the download normally happens,or even it would be helpful if someone can point out some resources..

Thanks

Comment: Never mind i did write a flash player for this purpose.Others doesnt seem to work at all